# How to specify a vector full of means with degrees of freedom for a Lack of Fit F-Test in R

Tags: r, function, format

Currently I'm working through *Applied Linear Models $5^{th}$ ed - by Kutner, et al*. A question I'm working on is asking me to perform an F-Test for Lack of Fit on my linear model. The linear model is a simple linear model of one parameter nothing too troublesome.

To perform the test one has to assess the difference between the full model and the reduced model. At this current junction the authors have stated to take the full model as $\hat{\mu_{j}} = \bar{Y_{j}}$. Specifically the screenshot below says the following:

[image]

The reduced model would be  the simple linear model:

[image]

I have no problem being able to do this manually within R, by computing the necessary values where need be as I've done for other questions. But I'm trying to improve my R skill set and this is where my problem lies.

I have done some reading to other answers related to this and model comparison can be done directly in the `anova()` function. But I'm having issues stating my full model correctly to be able to leverage the `anova()` function. I thought about computing a "vector of means" for the subgroups of data (which I display here just for completeness)

[image]

But I'm going to run into the problem of the `anova()` function most likely not being able to compute the degrees of freedom correctly. My data set is very small and this seems like the sort of situation that would show up all the time. With huge data sets I wouldn't see it being feasible to compute things manually so surely there has to be a way for me to phrase my Full Model properly to allow for the computation of means from the subgroups of replicates. But how do I do so? is the question of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness and posterity an answer was given on a sister site I asked this question on:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539958/how-to-specify-a-vector-full-of-means-with-degrees-of-freedom-for-a-lack-of-fit

the mods can delete the question if they deem fit and doesn't contribute to the community.